# Filter data using dropdown menu using only php

Tags: php, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a problem about a drop-down menu. I retrieved the data from my database in order to create the actual drop-down menu and now I want to use it for filtering purposes. I managed to get the "SEARCH" field working and actually filtering the results based on what the user typed, but I want also to allow the user to filter the data by selecting a specific town from the drop down menu. When the user chooses a town from the list I want to retrieve all the informations from the jobs table (jobname, jobtype, town, department, experiencelevel).  I searched this website and I couldn't find any topic about doing this with only PHP code. I also included the connection with the database.

I tried to get it working with `if(isset($_POST['dropbox']))` same as I did with the search field, but it just gives me no results every time I choose something.

Creating the drop-down code:

```
<div class="sect1">
<h2> Finding a job has never been so easy! </h2>
<div class="jobsearchbox">
    <h3> Search for opportunities </h3>
    <form action="jobsearch.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="indexjobsearch" placeholder="What job are you looking for?"/> <br>
        <select name ='dropbox'>
        <?php
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $jobtypename = $rows['town'];
            echo "<option hidden disabled selected value> Which town? </option>
                    <option name='selecttype' value='typejob'> $jobtypename </option>";
        }
        ?> 
        </select><br>
        <button type="submit" name="job-search"> Search now </button>
        </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was, the value of your option tag was static(value='typejob') so in that case, no matter which option the user selected it was always going to return "typejob" instead of the value the user selected. To fix the problem you just have to change the value of your option tag from "typejob" to "$jobtypename" as i have done in the code below.

```
<div class="sect1">
   <h2> Finding a job has never been so easy! </h2>
   <div class="jobsearchbox">
     <h3> Search for opportunities </h3>
     <form action="jobsearch.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="indexjobsearch" placeholder="What job are you 
        looking for?"/> <br>
        <select name ='dropbox'>
        <?php
            while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $jobtypename = $rows['town'];
                echo "
                    <option hidden disabled selected value> Which town? </option>
                    <option name='selecttype' value='$jobtypename'> $jobtypename 
                    </option>
                ";
            }
        ?> 
       </select><br>
       <button type="submit" name="job-search"> Search now </button>
     </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i figured that myself earlier this day. Your answer is correct, I gave you the green thingy because probably if I wasn't stubborn to spend literally the entire day figuring it out, this would have been a life saver. Thanks :)